# Ajax call with setInterval does not fetch new data from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a project where i need to display users details depending on date and time after given interval.I am using below code but it does not work as per my requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('registrationc/map')?>",
    // data: "unit_id="+unitid,
    data: { startDate: startdate, endDate: enddate, status: status },
    success: function (data) {
      marker(data);
    },
  });
  refresh();
});

function refresh() {
  setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "Post",
      url: "<?php echo site_url('registrationc/map')?>",
      // data: "unit_id="+unitid,
      data: { startDate: startdate, endDate: enddate, status: status },
      success: function (data) {
        alert("success 2");
        alert(data);
        marker(data);
      },
    });
  }, 30000);
}

function marker_map(data){
    var locations=JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.5937,78.9629),//{ lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629 }
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP//HYBRID //SATELLITE//TERRAIN
    });

    var marker, i;
    //var contentString ='<div id="iw-container"><div class="iw-title" align="center"></div>';
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
    { 
        var url="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/";
        if(locations[i]['status']=="green")
        {
            url+="green"+"-dot.png";
        }
        else if(locations[i]['status']=="yellow")
        {
            url+="yellow"+"-dot.png";
        }
        else if(locations[i]['status']=="orange")
        {
            url+="orange"+"-dot.png";
        }
        else
        {
            url+="red"+"-dot.png";
        }
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['lat'], locations[i]['longi']),
    icon:{url:url},
    map: map});

    var land=locations[i][1];
    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
     '<div class="iw-title">Patients Details</div>'+
      '<h5 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Patients Details</h5>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru'+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    var content = '<div id="iw-container">' +
                    '<div class="iw-title">'+locations[i]['firstname']+'</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-content">' +
                      '<div class="iw-subTitle">STATUS:'+locations[i]['status']+'</div>' +
                      '<div class="iw-subTitle">PERSONAL DETAILS</div>'+
                      '<h6>Age:'+locations[i]['age']+'</h6>'+
                      '<h6>Gender:'+locations[i]['gender']+'</h6>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>' +
                  '</div>';  
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:content});

        return function() {
          //infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          //marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png');
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

ajax function is called after given time interval but it does not fetch new data from database.for example if there are three entries in database during 1st call and than after given interval 2nd call also fetch only three entries even if there are five entries.how do i change the code to get expected result.

Comment: code look ok to me. how about code in `maker` ??

Comment: issue may be with `startDate: startdate, endDate: enddate, status: status` how you are creating variables ?

Comment: I have set variables as var today = new Date();

var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
var time1=" 00:00";

var status="all";

var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

var startdate = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd+''+time1;
var enddate = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd+' '+time;

Comment: and  code in marker is to plot markers on google map from the data fetched from database.

Comment: can u check my answer! it would be good if you add all these details to questions.

Comment: Ok ill try below code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213347/discussion-between-xdeepakv-and-nisha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue seems with data that you pass to ajax call. Like start date and end date.

> Please try below sample:

```
function getStats() {
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
  var time1 = " 00:00";
  var status = "all";
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  var startdate = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd + "" + time1;
  var enddate = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd + " " + time;
  return { startdate, enddate, status };
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  let { startdate, enddate, status } = getStats();
  $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('registrationc/map')?>",
    data: { startDate: startdate, endDate: enddate, status: status },
    success: function (data) {
      marker(data);
    },
  });
  refresh();
  function refresh() {
    setInterval(function () {
      let { enddate } = getStats();
      $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('registrationc/map')?>",
        data: { startDate: startdate, endDate: enddate, status: status },
        success: function (data) {
          marker(data);
        },
      });
    }, 30000);
  }
});
```

Comment: did u try to reduce time to 3000ms.. try even the call is working or not.

Comment: Yes call is working but it gets same data as previous call.

Comment: If i refresh from browser its gets all the data along with new entries.

Comment: it meaning, `startDate: startdate, endDate: enddate` logic is wrong.. how u create ?

Comment: need to remove enddate = new Date().getTime();  as you are using let { enddate } = getStats(); to assign enddate. this is the only change i did to your code and it works.

Comment: yes, missed.!! Thanks.. If is this answer ur question please accept as answer.!

Comment: Thanx @ xdeepakv